# How to run installed packages with npm

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, package, npm-scripts

I have a problem, which may be very obvious to many, but not so much to me, what happens is that in python I was used to installing packages and immediately using them without any problem (for example https://github.com/spotDL/spotify-downloader). However, I try to do the same in node, but it does not allow me, for example I would like to use https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper, however when I carry out the steps that the page indicates, I cannot execute the command, I would like to add that I have Node installed, and that I installed the package without any problem. However I can't use it, (I don't need to implement in any project, I just would like to take a look at the tool)... Any help you can give me would be excellent.
I would like to clarify that I am using Windows for this.

Comment: Is it giving you any errors? What command did you use to install it? You should just be able to execute it as you would any other command.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the package globally with `-g` flag.

```
npm i -g tiktok-scraper
tiktok-scraper <args>
```

Alternatively, you can use npx

```
npx tiktok-scraper <args>
```